# my eclipse is showing ensure adb location error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

Hey guys I am building an app and whenever I try to run app it shows a error of adb location and I have already started adb many times and also restart eclipse but it is showing same error please help me..

```
[2012-07-04 11:24:25 - The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occurred.
[2012-07-04 11:24:25 - You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2012-07-04 11:24:25 - Please ensure that adb is correctly located at '/home/ASDK/platform-tools/adb' and can be executed
```

Comment: hey golu if you have answer then suggest me...if you have no answer then do not give ratting in minus. ok

Comment: Your question has your answer that's why you are getting -1 rating and i am not giving you -1 because you already have less point.

Comment: actually mohsin I am new in android and have no more experience but  I have tried to solve with my self but I could not solve it if you have answer then suggest me

Comment: restart emulator or eclipse and check given path of adb...If you still have problem than download other sdk.

Answer (score 1):

Just restart Eclipse and device and go to task manager find adb.exe -> End Task.
You will not find any error after that.